# Medical instruments for pushing something out of the way

Tags: terminology, surgery

In the [Russian classification of medical instruments](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/gost-25725-89), some instruments are grouped under the title "medical instruments for moving aside":

> [image]

The description says:

> "Instruments whose working surfaces are paddle- or jaw-shaped and are connected by hinges, screws, or springs, and which serve the purpose of widening the wounds, cavities and passages in order to move aside those organs that are not intended for surgery, so as to protect those organs from accidental damage."

I think this "medical instruments for moving aside" is a very poor translation. What would be the natural-sounding English alternative? I tried googling but found nothing.

Displacing instruments?

I'm proofreading a text in which there's a table with a short description of the types of surgical instruments, and this particular type is indicated by the single word **pushing**. I'm not sure that an English speaker will understand which group of instruments this **pushing** might describe.

Comment: I don't think it's such a bad translation.

Comment: @CareyGregory - then I must have been over-cautious

Comment: @CopperKettle, you seem to be right. Those instruments do not _push_ things away, but they _keep the things apart._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "[retractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retractor_(medical))" is a category of instruments used for that purpose, perhaps "retracting instruments" or "retracting and exposing instruments" would work - I see both terms in use.

In my own experience, which is limited to rodent surgeries, we don't differentiate between pushing and pulling versions.